# Get the distict ID from table where status for that ID is 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below,

| ProdID | ProdName | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | AAA | 1 |
| 201 | BBB | 0 |
| 201 | CCC | 0 |
| 302 | DDD | 1 |
| 302 | EEE | 1 |
| 432 | FFF | 0 |

Now, I want the only ProdID 302 in output.
Reason: Only 302 has the Paid value 1 in all 302 rows

Please help me with this SQL query. Also, I want to Select only ProdID and not the entire columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` if you want the rows:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.prodId = t.prodId and
                        t2.paid <> 1
                 );
```

Use aggregation if you want only the id:

```
select prodId
from t
group by prodId
having min(paid) = 1;
```

Note:  This assumes that `paid` only takes on the values `1` and `0`.  If it can take on other values, you can use:

```
having sum(case when paid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
```

Comment: I cannot use select * command due to some restriction